# PHP 'most popular' feature on blog

Tags: php, mysql, statistics, traffic

i have a blog system which has articles inside a database, now i want to build a feature where it displays five of the most popular articles in the database, according to how many views it gets. 
Is there any sort of technology out there which i can take advantage of where it states how many views a page has received, and IS able to be integrated into a database.

Or perhaps there is a better internal method of doing something like this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: If you are going do down vote my thread randomly, at least tell me why.

Comment: Well, you don't think telling _which_ "blog system" you are using might be a good idea? (I hesitate to downvote because of this...) Try to think from your readers point of view: what details are really required? You have to tell these!

Comment: @arkascha I am using my own blog system, the reason i didnt include this information is because i think it is irreverent, tell me what information you wish to be included and i will show you.

Comment: Seeing my code for blog system will not help you suggesting which technology i can use to retrieve statistics on my pages.

Comment: Well, the sole information that this is something self tailored is already very helpful. Because for all "typical" systems read-to-use features for this exist, so you would likely have received tons of hints to that without.

Comment: Yes, although one hint i can give you guys is that there already lots of software out there that records statistics regarding the traffic on your pages, but ideally i would need something that gives me access to this information, so then i could write code to display my articles in order of traffic ( popularity )

Comment: If you want to go with one of those solutions (if you need it anyways, certainly not "just" for this feature), then I advise to take a look at "piwik". Once you have that data (it maintains an own database), then you can query the data you need from that database by means of sql, so in a generic manner. An alternative would be "awstats", more precise, less beautiful, but just file based, so its harder to extract data from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three choices as an approach for this obviously:

- you collect the usage count inside your database (a click counter)
- you extract that information from the http servers access log file later
- you could implement a click counter based on http server request hits

Both approaches have advantages and disadvantages. The first obviously means you have to implement such a counter and modify your database scheme. The second means you have asynchronous behavior (not always bad), but the components depend on each other, so your setup gets more complex. So I would advise for the first approach.

A click counter is something really basic and typical for all cms/blog systems and not that complex to implement. Since the content is typically generated dynamically (read: by a script) you typically have one request per view, so it is trivial to increment a counter in a table recording views of pages. From there your feature is clear: read the top five counter values and display a list of five links to those pages.

If you go with the second approach then you will need to store that extracted information, since log files are rotated, compressed, archived and deleted. So you either need a self tailored database for that or some finished product. But as said: this approach is much more complex in the end.

The last option is nothing I saw, it just sprang to my mind. You could for example use phps (just as an example) auto append feature to run a counting routine in a generic way. That routine could interpret the request url, decide if it was a request to an article view. If so it could raise a click counter, typically in a small database, since you might have several requests at the same time, which speaks against using a file. but why make things that xomplex? Go with the first option.

Comment: Thanks for the response, your first option was what i wanted to do before, but what if the user keeps spam clicking on a certain article, this will create false data and be easily abused, you see i dont know any other way other then just adding 1 to the field (counter) everytime a query is run to display an article, and like i said this could be easily abuse if someone spam clicks over and over again. any suggestions/hints/corrections?

Comment: Is that really an abuse? I'd say this is _use_. Think of it in a technical way: how many times _has_ an article be requested? The answer is obvious. Apart from that you'd have the same issue with all approaches, since you _count http requests_. Anyways: you could easily filter that out: just set a session variable on the server side which tracks all articles viewed by a user inside a session. Then you can decide to only increment the counter when the user requests a _new_ article he did not view before inside the current session.

Comment: Well yes i would consider this an abuse if a user clicks on an article then keeps refreshing it over and over again to mess with my statistics.

Comment: Ok, your decision. It certainly is not from a technical point of view, since he only uses the service you offer. But as said: you can easily filter that out. You could even blog such requests and display an error message, if you are that concerned (whyever, what is so terrible with that?).

Comment: I fail to understand how you dont think this is an issue. If you are trying to display top 5 legitimately popular articles, then why would it not be a concern to you if mabey two (if not more) of the articles there are actually only viewed by 1 person (who spams and makes the server think hundreds of people have viewed it), perhaps the health and legitimacy of your website doesnt matter to you.

Comment: Regardless, your answer has been very helpful my friend, thanks alot. Now will you maybe give me some more information about how i can make and use these session variables or i will have to make a new thread? Thanks again.

Comment: Experience says that such "threads" are simply not an issue from a certain size of a page on. About the session variables: just check the php documentation for its session feature (which you most likely already use). Also there are literally millions of examples out there on google about this: using phps session function you can maintain variables that are shared by many separate requests, so you have some kind of persistent memory between scripts. That is called a "session". So you just create an array inside such a variable and note down each page viewed inside that.